# How do I get this movie texture to animate as projected on an object?

Tags: texturing, uv, project

I'm just trying to get a movie texture to play on an object - can't seem to get it to play in Blender 2.8 (when pressing space).

[The project can be found here.](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AggYP6QsQK1_gkaZrYMvzYzB2FIL)

Can anybody suggest a solution?